# Setup Mono 3.0.1 in MonoDevelop 2.8 on Windows

Tags: monodevelop

I have installed MonoDevelop 2.8.2 using the windows .Net runtimes for now. I would like to use the latest Mono binaries (3.0.1) instead. To achieve that I´ve installed Mono 3.0.1 for windows from here

I´ve added the runtime in MonoDevelop via Tools->Options->Preferences->.NET Runtimes so that it shows up correctly in the list and set it as default. I made sure that my project uses this runtime (Project->Active Runtime->Mono 3.0.1). When I build a simple console project now I get the following error:

> Build failed.The specified executable is not a valid application for
>   this OS platform.

Can anybody shed some light whats going wrong here?

Comment: Your link is bad. Also what is your version of Windows? And is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Also, I've flagged this question for migration to StackOverflow.

Comment: The error seems quite clear. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform. Which executable did you set with  in your second paragraph? What do you get when you try to run it directly? (the same error?) And as Thraka asked, what is your OS? (e.g. win7-32 bit) and which version did you download (a 64 bit only version?)

Comment: Sorry the link I wanted to post is this: [link](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)

Comment: I run a Win7 64bit. I just run mono --version and it states that the supported platform is x86. I guess this is the problem then. Setting the project compiler setting to x86 did not help. It seems that I need a x64 version of mono.